# org-mode, auto new line at 80th column?

Tags: org-mode, auto-fill-mode

When I'm writing in `org-mode` I want it to automatically handle the creation of new lines similar to MS Word.

Can anyone recommend an `.emacs` config that will only apply to `org-mode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq fill-column 80)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)
```

It enables a minor mode called `auto-fill-mode` that does exactly what you asked and sets the column where the line break happens to `80` (only for org-mode!).

EDIT:

To be consistent with [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Turning-on-auto_002dfill-by-default.html) you could use

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq fill-column 80)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Even though I'm not sure what is the difference between both of them.

Comment: In earlier Emacs versions `xxx-mode` toggled a minor mode, so minor modes often provided an additional function `turn-on-xxx-mode`. However, in newer versions of Emacs, `xxx-mode` only toggles a mode when called interactively -- so that it should be possible to add it to a hook.

Comment: Thanks. I add the two lines to my init.el. After I reload init.el by M-x load-file, it doesn't work. Even I further reopen a file in a new buffer, and switch to org-mode, still not work. May I ask how to make the change take effective?

Comment: Can it be run after each save?